# MICBias Ground in audio codec

Tags: voltage, audio, microphone, audio-codec

MICBias is the voltage required for microphone to power and record signal at full levels.

What will happen if we ground MICBias, is it means we are disabling microphone.

[image]

Comment: what does the data-sheet for that chip say say is connected to the micbias pin.  it's likely that grounding it will increase the power consumption of the chip slightly. is `MICBIAS` connected to other parts of the device, or only to the chip and capacitor?

Comment: As per the datasheet: "
It is the voltage that a device needs and is designed to receive in order to function properly. In the case of microphones, it is the voltage that a microphone is supposed to receive in order to be able to power and record signal at full levels."  It is only connected to chip and capacitor

Answer (score 1):

Yes, grounding MICBIA will cut off Mic. or at least attenuate greatly.

---

All electret mics need a bias since they have a common source FET at some current such that Rbias (ext) determines mic source gain and **(xIP-xIN)pp max.**

Shorting MICBIAs would result in poor mic sensitivity.

You must choose Rbias so  expected input level optimizes SNR quality.
Make **VMID well above (xIP-xIN)pp** to allow for Rbias drop.

Choose VMID for  **MICBIAs = 2x(0.8)=1.6 x VMID.**

Then VMID becomes ADC Vref i.e. maximum input which gives you a few choices of gain from AVDD1.

The datasheet must give more details.

That would be my approach....

Comment: doesn't really say anything about the circuit shown.

Comment: what ?? my answer or the datasheet?  (-1)     ......  xIP = LIP< RIP